# How can I filter by a value inside a pivot table (using Prisma)?

Tags: prisma, prisma2

I'm building a bike rental app where users can reserve bikes for a certain number of days. Bikes and users have a many-to-many relationship, there's a bike_user pivot table that contains the information about reservation start and end dates. See the diagram:
[image: bikerr]

My schema looks kinda like this:

```
model User {
  id            String @id @default(cuid())
  username      String @unique
  email         String @unique
  rented_bikes  BikeUser[]
}


model Bike {
  id              String @id @default(cuid())
  model           String
  color           String
  rented_by_users BikeUser[]
}

model BikeUser {
  user                      User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId                    String
  bike                      Bike @relation(fields: [bikeId], references: [id])
  bikeId                    String
  reservation_start_date    DateTime 
  reservation_end_date      String

  @@id([userId, bikeId])
}
```

My goal is to take a range of dates, and filter the bikes, showing only the ones that haven't been reserved between these two dates.

Can you please help me figure out how to do this?